# Extension method gives compilation error when can be accessed as static method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, extension-methods, .net-6.0

I declared an extension method as follows

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        const string Nil = "$$$NIL$$$";
        public static bool IsEmptyNullOrNil(this string str)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || str == Nil)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my controller class, I included the namespace. But the program does not compile. But I could use the function as normal static method.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The point of an extension method is to appear as an *instance* method, not a static method of the class you're extending. As an aside, in recent versions of C# your method can be succinctly written as `=> str is "" or null or Nil`, using pattern matching, and at that point it's concise enough that it might be left out entirely, by just making `Nil` available in the context of code (which could be done with `using static`, for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your extension method can be accessed in the following ways

```
if (!employeeFilter.Name.IsEmptyNullOrNil())
```

OR

```
if (!MyExtensions.IsEmptyNullOrNil(employeeFilter.Name))
```